# how to make MediaElement to take the whole space of a Grid?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, visual-studio, mediaelement

I have a MediaElement in a Grid , and i want it to take the entire space when i play it.
here is my code:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                <Grid.Background>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="Resource/bgrdMedia.png" Stretch="None"/>
                </Grid.Background>

                <MediaElement x:Name="VideoControl" LoadedBehavior="Manual" UnloadedBehavior="Stop"
                              Stretch="Uniform" StretchDirection="DownOnly" MediaEnded="Element_MediaEnded"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                               VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  />

            </Grid>
```

but i have that: [image]

any ideas! thanks !

Comment: And without the "Uniform"  and "DownOnly" ?

Comment: The snippet isn't ideal for seeing what is going on. I think your player is filling (its part of) the grid. Make a complete sample and use use solid background colors and visible gridlines to convince us/yourself it isn't .

Comment: @HenkHolterman :I have tried with and without and with all possibilities :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By setting the `StretchDirection` to `DownOnly` you are preventing it from scaling upwards:

> DownOnly | The content scales downward only when it is larger than the parent. If the content is smaller, no scaling upward is performed.

[Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.stretchdirection(v=vs.110).aspx)

If you leave the `StretchDirection` as `Both` (the default) and have the horizontal and vertical alignments as `Stretch` (which you have) it should give the result you want.

Note, however, that upscaling may result in a blurred or pixelated image if the original media isn't of sufficiently high resolution.

Comment: There's a tutorial here - http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/audio-video/playing-video/ - but it doesn't go in to scaling

Comment: I did what you told me but I left Stretch="Fill" , would that have an impact on Strechdirection ?